# Is it possible to hide all the default markers from google map such as restaurants, parks

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm going to develop an android mobile application in which a user will select a road and my application will suggest him all the restaurants or hotel which are defined by me.

what I need

1. don't want to show the restaurants or hotels suggested by google map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `Hiding map features`. Refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features)

Update: You can play with this [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) and it will generate the `json` for you

Define a raw resource in /res/raw/style_json.json

```
[
 {
   "featureType": "poi.business",
   "elementType": "all",
   "stylers": [
     {
       "visibility": "off"
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

and assign it to your map.

```
boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));
```